# How can I remove the extra space that appears in Xcode 9 when defining inline documentation for a parameter?

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, xcode9

I have defined some inline documentation in Xcode 9.4.1 like this:

```
/**
    Initiates a timer that counts down to zero from a passed-in value defined in CXP. If the timer reaches zero, it executes a method to log out the user.
    - parameter duration: An integer expressed in seconds that defines the time a user has to choose an action before being automatically logged out.
    - returns: `doLogout()` only if the timer reaches zero.
 */
```

But when I view this documentation, there is a space in front of the parameter name `duration`:

[image]

Gabriel Theodoropolous wrote an informative [post](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-markdown/) entitled *Documenting Your Swift Code in Xcode Using Markdown* in May 2016. In it, he provides a screen shot under the *Keywords* section where there is clearly no extra space– everything lines up nicely.

[image]

While our versions of Xcode differ (he was using Xcode 7), it seems crazy that if this is a bug, it would not have been fixed by now.

I have attempted to remove the space through a lot of trial and error but nothing has worked.

How can I remove the space in front of `duration`?

---

MORE CODE FOR REFERENCE:

```
class AutomaticLogoutTimer {
    fileprivate var duration: Int = 0
    fileprivate var timer: Timer = Timer()
    fileprivate var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

/**
    Initiates a timer that counts down to zero from a passed-in value defined in CXP. If the timer reaches zero, it executes a method to log out the user.
    - parameter duration: An integer expressed in seconds that limits the time a user has to choose an action before being automatically logged out.
    - returns: `doLogout()` only if the timer reaches zero.
 */
    public func startTimer(duration: Int) {
        self.duration = duration
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            self.duration -= 1
            if(self.duration == 0) {
                self.stopTimer()
                return self.doLogout()
            }
        }
    }
    // a little more code here
}
```

Comment: The popup template changes all the time. You will get a different popup on Xcode 10 so why nitpicking over a *space* in the documentation?

Comment: On your screenshot, it is written "Parameters" and not "Parameter", in front of the extra space. This means that there is another problem, that may be linked to the extra space. Please, can you write the source code of the whole definition of startTimer that is in your swift file?

Comment: @CodeDifferent, curiosity

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo, I think CodeDifferent is correct, it's just some random change in the popup but I've added the source code in my question for reference.